# jsp usebean gives errror in Netbeans

Tags: java

This simple JSP page give me error in at <jsp:useBean in Netbeans:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Beans</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:useBean id="students" class ="com.tutorialspoint.StudentsBean"/>
        <div>Beans and stuff</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: have you read the error message? it shows exactly what you're doing wrong. Personally, I would advice against using tutorialspoint or similar sites in order to learn

Comment: Which error here is “correct”, I wonder?